# phonegap build non-whitespace before first tag

Tags: xml, cordova, phonegap-build

I am finding solutions. and found workaround at
[http://www.multiasking.com/blog/xml2js-sax-js-non-whitespace-before-first-tag](http://www.multiasking.com/blog/xml2js-sax-js-non-whitespace-before-first-tag/)
but I don't know how to parse xml data. Absolutely I don't use xml data except config.xml ... etc (phonegap/cordova support file or data)

Where do I use this code ???
`var cleanedString = origString.replace("\ufeff", "");`

Comment: This is BOM and BOM differs depending on encoding: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark. Not sure how you read contents but typically this should be taken care of for you if you are using file APIs.

Comment: Okay, thanks for comment. I found solution. In my case, just remove and add platform. It's working. thanks again.